# error insert sql dump to mysql using docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I try to import my existing `backup.sql.gz` in mysql using docker. this is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}-mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysqldumps/backup.sql.gz:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

when I try to run `docker-compose up` i got an error:

ERROR: for 52bf24fa5ad1_project  Cannot start service mysql: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused "rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \"project/mysqldumps/backup.sql\" to rootfs \"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/be2a6a81a405ab94e956086e578ecec2a98207ef53c8f85aaaf053d79d3c183a/merged\" ...

How can I fix it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that the mount path of the volume is not existing.

Comment: how to add mount?